How do I make a child component visible only when the parent is hovered in FluentUI + React?
StackBlitz here
I'm trying to create a card component that represents a delete-able item, and I want the delete button to only be visible when the card is hovered.
According to what I've found, this styling should do the trick, but the delete button is stubbornly staying hidden.
const styles = makeStyles({
    itemContainer: { }
    buttonContainer: {
        visibility: "hidden",
    },
    "&:hover .buttonContainer": {
        visibility: "visible",
    },
});

// later in that same scope...

<Card
    key={"savedItem" + index}
    className={styles.item}
    appearance="subtle"
    onClick={() => {
        // load item
    }}
>
    <CardHeader
        image={<AirplaneRegular/>}
        header={item.displayName}
        action={
            <div className={styles.buttonContainer}>
                <Button
                    icon={<Delete16Regular />}
                    appearance="subtle"
                    onClick={(e) => {
                        // delete item
                        e.stopPropagation();
                    }}
                />
            </div>
        }
    />
</Card>

What am I doing wrong here?

In makeStyles you should define
  card: {
    width: '360px',
    maxWidth: '100%',
    height: 'fit-content',
    '& .buttonContainer': {
      visibility: 'hidden',
    },
    ':hover': {
      '& .buttonContainer': {
        visibility: 'visible',
      },
    },
  },

and the button container should have the class buttonContainer
Working code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ff53e2-zpmwug?file=src%2Fexample.tsx

Very nice! I noticed that the class name now has to be hardcoded as a string literal rather than by referencing the styles object. Is there not a way to keep linked variable names when doing this? Best I've figured out is this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ff53e2-rabwnx?file=src%2Fexample.tsx but that's still a bit funky compared to every other className reference.

It seems to me that you can't keep the names because they are independent of each other. What you want to do requires a parent -> child relationship.
